# Facebook new like box - missing translation

Tags: facebook-like, translation

Sorry to bother you guys. I have a bilingual site that includes a Facebook Like Box (www.iskio.ca). 
Depending on the language i will build the FB widget using the proper locale (fr_CA or en_US)

i.e. : src="http://connect.facebook.net/'.$lang.'/all.js#xfbml=1" where $lang is either fr_CA or en_US

It all works fine, except that recently it seems FB made changes to the Like Box, notably by removing the names under thumbnails, and added the text **'You and xxx others like yyy'**.

This text is **not translated in fr_CA locale**, it does seem to be translated in fr_FR tough.

**Q:** Is there a form somewhere where we can inform FB of such bugs or submit translations? (i always end up redirected to the somewhat useless help pages). Is there a way to 'force' our own translated strings (i don't think so).

Switching from fr_CA to fr_FR is not an option. Thanks!

Comment: Precision: if i disconnect from my own FB account, the string 'xxx people like yyy' in the FB likebox is translated. So it's only one specific string missing in the translation.

Comment: You need an app to file a bug here. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs